# How to read an online file from a Thread using wxWidgets

Tags: c++14, wxwidgets

I have a problem trying to read an online file from a thread. The same code works correctly if is not inside a thread. But if it is inside of the thread, the application dies.

The thread also works correctly if I do not try to read the file.

**The following code works correctly:**

```
wxInputStream *httpStream; ///it is a global variable.

void contadorFrame::ConnetAndRead()     
{    
    wxHTTP get;
    get.SetHeader(_T("Content-type"), _T("text/xml; charset=utf-8"));
    get.SetTimeout(10);

    wxString  sever, path;
    getURLParts(TextCtrl_url->GetValue(), sever, path);   


    while (!get.Connect(sever ,80 ))
     wxSleep(5);

    httpStream = get.GetInputStream( path );

    if (get.GetError() == wxPROTO_NOERR)
    { 
        wxString xml_buff;
        wxStringOutputStream out_stream(&xml_buff);

        httpStream->Read(out_stream);
        std::string standarize( estandarizaXML( xml_buff.ToStdString() ) );
        readXML(standarize.c_str());///read file from buffer
    }
    else
    {
        wxMessageBox(_T("Unable to connect!"));
    }

    wxDELETE(httpStream);
    get.Close();
}
```

**I know I should avoid using GUI functions inside threads, and so I'm trying this way.**

```
void contadorFrame::ConnetAndRead() 
{   
    wxHTTP get;
    get.SetHeader(_T("Content-type"), _T("text/xml; charset=utf-8"));
    get.SetTimeout(10);

    wxString  sever, path;
    getURLParts(TextCtrl_url->GetValue(), sever, path);


    while (!get.Connect(sever ,80 ))
     wxSleep(5);

    httpStream = get.GetInputStream( path );

    if (get.GetError() == wxPROTO_NOERR)
    {
        PerformCalculation(); // create and run the thread
    }
    else
    {
        wxMessageBox(_T("Unable to connect!"));
    }

    wxDELETE(httpStream);
    get.Close();
}

void contadorFrame::PerformCalculation()// create and run the thread    
{    
    m_pThread = new MyThread(this, httpStream);
    m_pThread->Create();

    if ( m_pThread->Run() != wxTHREAD_NO_ERROR )
    {
        wxLogError("Can't create the thread!");
        delete m_pThread;
        m_pThread = NULL;
    }
}
```

**The following code works incorrectly**

```
void *MyThread::Entry()    
{    
    wxCommandEvent evt(wxEVT_MYTHREAD, GetId());

    wxString xml_buff;
    wxStringOutputStream out_stream(&xml_buff); 
    httpStream->Read(out_stream);               //this fails

    std::string standarize( estandarizaXML( xml_buff.ToStdString() ) );
    readXML(standarize.c_str());///read file from buffer

    wxPostEvent(m_pHandler, evt);
    return (wxThread::ExitCode)0; // success
}
```

Anyone can help to solve this problem? Another way to do the same?
Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution. But it does not work totally fine !!

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_socket_base.html

When using wxSocket from multiple threads, even implicitly (e.g. by using wxFTP or wxHTTP in another thread) you must initialize the sockets from the main thread by calling Initialize() before creating the other ones.

```
void contadorFrame::ConnetAndRead() 
{   
    wxHTTP get;
    get.Initialize();


    get.SetHeader(_T("Content-type"), _T("text/xml; charset=utf-8"));
    get.SetTimeout(10);

    wxString  sever, path;
    getURLParts(TextCtrl_url->GetValue(), sever, path);


    while (!get.Connect(sever ,80 ))
     wxSleep(5);

    httpStream = get.GetInputStream( path );

    if (get.GetError() == wxPROTO_NOERR)
    {
        PerformCalculation(); // create and run the thread
    }
    else
    {
        wxMessageBox(_T("Unable to connect!"));
    }

    wxDELETE(httpStream);
    get.Close();
}
```

**this fails, but if i do (wxHTTP get) a global variable, like this, then it works**

```
wxHTTP get;
void contadorFrame::ConnetAndRead() 
{   

    get.Initialize();


    get.SetHeader(_T("Content-type"), _T("text/xml; charset=utf-8"));
    get.SetTimeout(10);

    wxString  sever, path;
    getURLParts(TextCtrl_url->GetValue(), sever, path);


    while (!get.Connect(sever ,80 ))
     wxSleep(5);

    httpStream = get.GetInputStream( path );

    if (get.GetError() == wxPROTO_NOERR)
    {
        PerformCalculation(); // create and run the thread
    }
    else
    {
        wxMessageBox(_T("Unable to connect!"));
    }

    wxDELETE(httpStream);
    get.Close();
}
```

**The problem now is that the debugger tells me a warning message like this.**

../../scr/common/socket.cpp(297): assert ""app"" failed to Init(): sockets can't be initialized without wxApp
Do you want to stop the program?

if I choose NO, the program runs perfect!!

What is the correct way to initialize the socket? That is, where should I put this (wxHTTP::Initialize()) to not receive warning messages from the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVE :-)**

**I did this**

```
bool contadorApp::OnInit()
{
    wxSocketBase::Initialize();

    //(*AppInitialize
    bool wxsOK = true;
    wxInitAllImageHandlers();
    if ( wxsOK )
    {
        contadorFrame* Frame = new contadorFrame(0);
        Frame->Show();
        SetTopWindow(Frame);
    }
    //*)
    return wxsOK;
}
```

**and this**

```
class contadorFrame: public wxFrame
{
    public:
      wxHTTP get;
};
```

**Now Works perfect!!**

**thx u guys!!**